# Spring dataflow Processor to process one payload and write multiple rows in data table

Tags: java, spring-data, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to ask a simple question,

I have implemented a processor, which process one payload and return an array of entities, such like:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class SimpleProcessor {
    ...
    public SimpleProcessor () {
        ...
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
            public OutgoingEntity[] processData(IncomingEntity payload) {

    // business logic here

    return outgoingEntity; 
}
```

I have my stream in SCDF and middleware as kafka like this:

```
some source | SimpleProcessor | JDBC sink
```

to validate the messages, I have replaced log sink to relpace JDBC sink and it logs arrays of json. When I use JDBC sink, it throws Exception and says JDBC sink can not access the properties in the object, which makes sense, that it is array of objects instead object...

My question is:

1. Can I use modify my processor, so it can process a payload once and give out message multiple time, like this,

   ```
   @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT)
   public void processData(IncomingEntity payload) {
       ...
       for(OutGoingEntity o: OutgoingEntity[]){ 
           outputMethode();
       }
   }

   @Transformer(outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
   private OutGoingEntity outputMethode() {
       .....
       return outGoingEntity; 
   }
   ```

   So it can pass multiple json object to jdbc sink and write in the datatable.
2. Can I use JDBC sink to deal with arrays? How?
3. Can I use some other processors or sink to finish this task?

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring, but in Kafka Streams you could either `flatTransform()` or `flatMap()` or similar to emit multiple records per input record. Or call `context.forward()` for a Processor API based implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Like Matthias J. Sax suggested in comment, I have used flatMapValue method of KStream to deal with array from input. I put this scdf processor after the one forwards array. That works fine.

```
@EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor.class)
public class ArrayProcessor {

@StreamListener("input") @SendTo("output")
public KStream<?, String> process(KStream<?, String> payload) {

    return payload.flatMapValues( //impl ) 

...} }
```