# SCDF processor reads one message and outputs arrays of objects, but sink can handle single item

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

My Processor process one payload and produce a List

```
  @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
  @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
  public List<XYZObject> getAll(
      XYZInput inp) {
      List<XYZObject> xyzs = dbService.findAllByDataType(inp.getDataType());
      return xyzs;
  }
```

The stream has RabbitMQ middleware, and my sink looks like below:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
  public void writeToX(XYZInput input) {
    ....
  }
```

I took a look into a similar discussion [Similar Problem with Kafka Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62087870/spring-dataflow-processor-to-process-one-payload-and-write-multiple-rows-in-data). How to achieve this with Rabbit binder?

Is it achieveable with RabbitMQ as binder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Spring Cloud Stream question and is controlled by the `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.consumer.batch-mode` property.

Please see the reference guide section for [Batch consumers/producers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_batch_consumers) to learn more.